# Getting generic type from the DeclaringType of a nested type in C# with reflection

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

Say I have the following class structure:

```
public class Outer<T>
{
    public class Inner<U>
    {
    }
}
```

And some code:

```
var testType = typeof(Outer<string>.Inner<int>);
```

How can I get the constructed generic type `typeof(Outer<string>)`, or the value of the generic `typeof(string)` from the `testType` variable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Interesting - it seems that the outer type's generic argument is projected to the inner type:

```
var testType = typeof(Outer<string>.Inner<int>);              
var outerType = testType.DeclaringType;                       
var outerTypeGenericParam = outerType.GetGenericArguments();
var testTypeGenericParam = testType.GetGenericArguments();
Console.WriteLine(outerType);                                 // Test+Outer`1[T] 
Console.WriteLine(outerTypeGenericParam[0]);                  // T
Console.WriteLine(testTypeGenericParam[0]);                   // System.String
Console.WriteLine(testTypeGenericParam[1]);                   // System.Int32
```

so the one-liner in your case would be:

```
testType.GetGenericArguments()[0]
```

Comment: You mean `testType.GetGenericArguments()[0]`? `testType.DeclaringType.GetGenericArguments()[0]` is giving me `typeof(T)`. Either way, good catch :)

Comment: @Shane. Good catch. Fixed.